# How can I make one action occur when a keyboard button is pressed rather than looping

Tags: java, button, keyboard, lwjgl

```
    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_I)) {
        if(ms != MenubarState.INVENTORY) ms = MenubarState.INVENTORY;
        else ms = MenubarState.CLOSED;
    }
```

This bit here is ran every render, so it obviously will be checking while the button is pressed. I want to be able to press it once, and only execute it once until I take my finger off and press it again.

How is this done? I am programming in java.

Answer (score 2):

You could just remember if you executed the action:

```
boolean done = false;
if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_I)) {
    if(!done){
       if(ms != MenubarState.INVENTORY) ms = MenubarState.INVENTORY;
       else ms = MenubarState.CLOSED;
       done= true;
    }
}
else done= false;
```

Comment: This is one way I have considered, although for multiple buttons it could get messy

Comment: you could wrap this in its own class or method to make it more readable

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend you take a look at these:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

You can create a class that implements the Keylisterner interface and extends the Observable class. You can have your class with your render loop in it implement the Observer interface. If you make your render class an observer to your keylistener class you can have the keylistener call a method containing:

```
if(ms != MenubarState.INVENTORY) ms = MenubarState.INVENTORY;
    else ms = MenubarState.CLOSED;
```

exactly once when the correct key is pressed.

Comment: This seems a little farfetched, 2 new classes for this?

Answer (score 1):

LWJGL comes with a Keyboard.getEventKeyState(); If the key is being pressed, this will be true, false otherwise.

```
if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_I)) {
    if(Keyboard.getEventKeyState())
        ms = MenubarState.INVENTORY;
    else ms = MenubarState.CLOSED;
}
```

What this does is it checks to see if the key is being held down. If it is not, then the menu bar will be closed.

Comment: I dont know if this does what I want. The Keyboard.getEventKeyState is always returning false.